# Can't see tkinter buttons/labels in frame

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I defined 2 buttons and a label to the frame but I can't see them.
I tried with pack(), grid(), place().
if I comment out the frame lines I can see the effect on the container frame (right frame).

Bigger picture:

```
import tkinter as tk
import subprocess as sub
import multiprocessing as mp
import shutil
import time
import io
import os

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("640x478")
        self.title("Gil Shwartz GUI Project")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        menu = tk.Frame(self, height=250, width=10, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat", height=200, bg="black")
        menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", anchor="w")
        container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "MainWelcome", "TestPing", "PageOne", "UptimeCheck"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = MainWelcome(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = TestPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = UptimeCheck(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

class Menu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Ping Test", bg="royalblue2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="dark violet",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(4))
        buttun3 = tk.Button(self, text="Home", bg="pale goldenrod",
                            command=lambda : controller.show_frame(1))
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Quit", bg="gray40",
                            command=lambda: self.terminate())

        button1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        buttun3.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        button4.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

    def terminate(self):

        path = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/Gui-Skeleton'

        try:
            os.rmdir(path)
        except OSError as err:
            print(f"Error Deleting tmp folder! {err}")

        exit()


class MainWelcome(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        canvas = tk.Canvas(self, bg="black")
        canvas.pack(expand=True, fill="both")


class TestPing(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")
        self.controller = controller

        self.output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=325, width=580, padx=3, pady=3)
        self.output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)
        self.textbox = tk.Text(self, height=320, width=550, pady=3, padx=3)
        self.textbox.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill="both", expand=True)
        self.clear_file = tk.BooleanVar()
        self.clear_file.set(False)
        self.url_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter URL : ", padx=7, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        self.url_input_box = tk.Entry(self)
        self.url = self.url_input_box.get()
        self.url_input_box.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=0)
        self.file_name_label = tk.Label(self, text="Enter Filename: ", bg="skyblue1")
        self.file_name_input_box = tk.Entry(self)
        self.filename = self.file_name_input_box.get()
        self.default_file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/default-tmp.txt'
        self.clear_file_label = tk.Label(self, text="Clear File?", padx=5, pady=5, bg="skyblue1")
        self.clear_file_radio_yes = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="yes", value=True, var=self.clear_file, bg="skyblue1",
                                           command=lambda: self.callback(self.clear_file.get()))
        self.clear_file_radio_no = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="no", value=False, var=self.clear_file, bg="skyblue1",
                                          command=lambda: self.callback(self.clear_file.get()))
        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", width=10, height=1,
                                    command=lambda: self.condition(self.url_input_box.get(),
                                                             self.clear_file.get(), self.file_name_input_box.get()))
        self.clear_fields_button = tk.Button(self, text="Clear Fields", width=10,
                                      command=lambda: self.clear_boxes(self.url_input_box, self.file_name_input_box))

        self.url_label.pack(anchor="w")
        self.url_input_box.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        self.file_name_label.pack(anchor="w", padx=7, pady=5)
        self.file_name_input_box.pack(anchor="w", padx=10)
        self.clear_file_label.pack(anchor="w")
        self.clear_file_radio_yes.pack(anchor="w")
        self.clear_file_radio_no.pack(anchor="w")
        self.submit_button.pack(anchor="w", pady=1)
        self.clear_fields_button.pack(anchor="w")

    @classmethod
    def clear_boxes(self, urlInputBox, fileNameInputBox):
        urlInputBox.delete(0, "end")
        fileNameInputBox.delete(0, "end")

    @classmethod
    def callback(self, clearFile):
        print(f'Clear file = {clearFile}')  # Debugging Mode - check Radio box Var.

    def condition(self, host, clearFile, filenameInputBox):

        print(clearFile, filenameInputBox)  # Debugging - Input Validation
        if clearFile is True and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox == '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_no(host)
        elif clearFile is True and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)
        elif clearFile is False and filenameInputBox != '':
            self.handler_clr_no_fn_yes(host, filenameInputBox)

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_no(self, host):

        startprocs = []
        # nextprocs = []
        lastprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + WriteFile",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput",
                          target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output, args=(host,))
        # proc3 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + Generate PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        # proc4 = mp.Process(name="Clear + No Filename + PrintOutput to GUI",
        #                    target=self.clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui, args=(host,))
        proc5 = mp.Process(name="Remove first line + Write new default file",
                           target=self.delete_default_lines)

        startprocs.append(proc1)
        startprocs.append(proc2)
        # startprocs.append(proc3)
        # startprocs.append(proc4)

        # nextprocs.append(proc1)

        lastprocs.append(proc5)

        for s in startprocs:
            s.start()

        for s2 in startprocs:
            s2.join()

        # for n in nextprocs:
        #     n.start()
        #
        # for p in nextprocs:
        #     p.join()

        for l in lastprocs:
            l.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_no(self, host):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Append to default file",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_no_writefile, args=(host,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Print Output", target=self.clr_no_fn_no_printoutput, args=(host,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()

        for p in nextprocs:
            p.start()

    def handler_clr_yes_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []
        nextprocs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + userFilename + Write to file",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Clear file + user filename + Print output",
                           target=self.clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))
        proc3 = mp.Process(name="Remove Empty Lines from user filename",
                           target=self.delete_userfile_lines, args=(filenameInputBox,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)
        nextprocs.append(proc3)

        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()

        for p in procs:
            p.join()

        for np in nextprocs:
            np.start()

    def handler_clr_no_fn_yes(self, host, filenameInputBox):

        procs = []

        proc1 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Append to Userfile",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_writefile, args=(host, filenameInputBox,))
        proc2 = mp.Process(name="Keep File + Userfilename + Print Output",
                           target=self.clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput, args=(host,))

        procs.append(proc1)
        procs.append(proc2)

        for p in procs:
            p.start()

        for p2 in procs:
            p2.join()

    @classmethod
    def delete_default_lines(cls):

        time.sleep(1.5)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/default-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt'

        with open(file, 'r') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()
        os.remove(file)

    @classmethod
    def delete_userfile_lines(cls, filename):

        time.sleep(1.5)
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        newfile = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt'

        with open(file, 'r+') as inp, open(newfile, 'w+') as out:
            for line in inp:
                if not line.isspace():
                    out.write(line.lstrip())
                    out.write('')
            inp.close()
            out.close()
        os.remove(file)

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", "4", f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def generate_clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self, host):
        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')

        sub.run(f"ping {host}", shell=True, capture_output=True)

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_print_output_to_gui(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.textbox.insert(tk.END, proc.stdout.decode())

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_no_writefile(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/default-tmp.txt'
        ping = sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE)
        with open(file, 'w+') as output:
            data = output.read()
            for line in ping.stdout.readlines():
                data += str(line.decode())
            ping.stdout.close()
            output.seek(0)
            output.write(data.lstrip())

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_printoutput(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}\n')
        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_no_writefile(self, host):

        print(f'Current Proccess: {mp.current_process().name} + {mp.current_process().pid}')
        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/default.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_yes_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):

        file = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/Gui-Skeleton/{filename}-tmp.txt'
        with open(file, 'w') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_printoutput(self, host):

        with sub.Popen(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=sub.PIPE,
                       bufsize=1, universal_newlines=True, stderr=sub.STDOUT) as p:
            for line in p.stdout:
                print(line, end=' ')

    @classmethod
    def clr_no_fn_yes_writefile(self, host, filename):

        with open(fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/Desktop/{filename}.txt', 'a') as output:
            sub.call(["ping", "-n", '4', f'{host}'], stdout=output)


class UptimeCheck(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="honeydew3", relief="flat")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        win7_label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose OS", padx=3)
        win7_label.pack()

        win7_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 7")
        win10_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 10")

        win7_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="n")
        win10_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="n")

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", bg="red")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to page 2",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(2))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    path = fr'c:/users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/Gui-Skeleton'

    try:
        os.mkdir(path)

    except OSError as err:
        print(f"[!] Operation failed! {err}")

    app = GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```

Uptime class:

```
class UptimeCheck(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Uptime Check", bg="honeydew3", relief="flat")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        win7_label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose OS", padx=3)
        win7_label.pack()

        win7_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 7")
        win10_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 10")

        win7_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="n")
        win10_button.pack(side=tk.TOP, anchor="n")
```

............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
[image]

Comment: That was a lot of code. Can you please identify which buttons you are having trouble with.

Comment: i pasted the specific class below the main code. i can't see anything but the frame.

Comment: Can't figure it out. But it seems that the LabelFrame with text "Uptime Check" is bigger than the parent..., It seems to me that widgets packed into the LabelFrame is there but you cant see them for some reason. If I run the UptimeCheck() class by itself in a root window it works.

Comment: Add `container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)` and `container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` inside `GUI.__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 - spot on! 
why didn't u put that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

You should have set the button's parent widget to be the frame rather than self.
To place an item inside a frame, the items parent should be the frame.

Change

```
win7_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 7")
```

to

```
win7_button = tk.Button(frame, text="Windows 7")
```

(and the same for your win10 button)

Comment: that did nothing unfortunately.
following acw1668's did the job for me.

Answer (score 1):

so this is the working code after acw's comment:

Uptime class:

```
class UptimeCheck(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="skyblue1")

        self.controller = controller
        self.output = tk.LabelFrame(self, text="Output", height=250, width=580,
                                    padx=3, pady=3, relief="flat")

        self.win7_label = tk.Label(self, text="Choose OS", padx=3, pady=10, bg="skyblue1")
        self.win7_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 7", borderwidth=2, padx=10)
        self.win10_button = tk.Button(self, text="Windows 10", borderwidth=2, padx=10)
        self.linux_debian = tk.Button(self, text="Linux Debian", borderwidth=2, padx=10)

        self.output.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        self.win7_label.pack(anchor="nw")
        self.win7_button.pack(anchor="nw")
        self.win10_button.pack(anchor="nw")
        self.linux_debian.pack(anchor="nw")
```

Main controller class:

```
class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("640x478")
        self.title("Gil Shwartz GUI Project")
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        menu = tk.Frame(self, height=250, width=10, relief="solid")
        container = tk.Frame(self, relief="flat", height=200, bg="black")
        menu.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", anchor="w")
        container.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="both", expand=True)
        menu.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = ["Menu", "MainWelcome", "TestPing", "PageOne", "UptimeCheck"]

        self.frames[0] = Menu(parent=menu, controller=self)
        self.frames[1] = MainWelcome(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[2] = TestPing(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[3] = PageOne(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[4] = UptimeCheck(parent=container, controller=self)

        self.frames[0].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[1].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[2].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[3].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.frames[4].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        print(frame)
        frame.tkraise()
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```